# How to pass data between function calls

Tags: c#, performance, function, class

We can pass data between functions by using class objects. Like i have class

```
public class AddsBean
    {
      public long addId{get;set;}
      public int bid { get; set; }
      public long pointsAlloted { get; set; }
      public string userId  { get; set; }
      public enum isApproved { YES, NO };
      public DateTime approveDate { get; set; }
      public string title { get; set; }
      public string description { get; set; }
      public string Link { get; set; }
      public DateTime dateAdded { get; set; }
    }
```

We can call function like `public List<AddsBean> getAdds(string Id)`. This approach is good when you need all the variables of class.  *But what if you need only 2 or 3 variables of class?*

Passing object of class is not good because it will be wastage of memory. Another possible solution is to make different classes of lesser variables but that is not practical.

What should we do that will best possible solution to fulfill motive and best according to performance also?

Comment: Your premise is not correct. More memory is not used. Well, aside from one extra reference on the stack.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - One extra reference on the stack which will again be removed once the stack rolls back to its caller.. :)

Comment: People often thinking about  performance of the software. i dont think this kind of issue(its not an issue) will damage the performance of your software. In this situation it never cost your memory. even if you have 100 fields in class, dont worry to read or clone the object. we are living a world where memory is very cheap. even my wrist watch has 128 K memmory.

Comment: The title of the question "how to pass data between function calls" is not correct. In OO you could refer to methods instead. I think it is an important question. May be you can name it "How to construct  lists of different properties from the same class". I suggest you change the name and the tag to get more audience interested.

Comment: @BinsonEldhose once very famous developer from microsoft said that don't judge any resource as cheap if you can improve it because even if your resource taking millisecond extra and used by million's of user's  your wasting minutes of world.

Comment: @HotCoolStud, i just concerned this particular case (your case),  please check how heap and stack working .NET

Comment: The thing is, you really *can't* improve things here.

Answer (score 1):

In Java - "References to objects are passed by value".. So, you dont pass the entire object, you just pass the reference to the object to the called function.

EG:

```
class A{
int i;
int j;
double k;
}

class B{
public static void someFunc(A a) // here 'a' is a reference to an object, we dont pass the object. 
{
 // some code
}
public static void main(String[] args){
A a = new A();
B.someFunc(a);  // reference is being passed by value
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, as Java is pass by value and references typed, there is no need to worry about the memory wastage.
next, as you have mentioned, it is not good to pass all the object if you do not need them all, in some situation, it's true.  as you need to protect your data in instance, thus you can use different granularity of class, for instance:

```
class A
{id, name}
class B extends A
{password,birthday}
```

by refer to different class you can control the granularity yourself, and provide different client with different scope of data.

But in some condition, you need to use a instance to store all data in the whole application, like `configure data` in `hadoop`, or some other configuration related instance.

Try to choose the most suitable scope!

Comment: This makes the problem worse. Marginally so, but still. You already have an object with the data. Just use that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I agree, but since question asker mentioned, I just provide a method!

Comment: @AndrewBarber I dont think what he said is the same as mine, I use `extends` for reuse, but he said create another one, totally different one. in addition, mine method can provide different encapsulation, much better that what he think. eventually, I still do not think it's good. just one of the idea

Comment: I misread, you are right; it is different! (Still not ideal, though... he should just pass the object and forget it!)

Comment: @AndrewBarber yeah, that is what most of software do, like `hadoop`, as a global readable instance go through the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that this is the source of problems and you don't want to define a new class with a subset of the properties, .NET provides the `Tuple` class for grouping a small number of related fields. For example, a `Tuple<int, int, string>` contains two integers and a string, in that order.

```
public Tuple<string, long, DateTime> GetPointsData()
{
    AddsBean bean = ... // Get your AddsBean somehow
    return Tuple.Create<string, long, DateTime>(bean.userId, bean.pointsAlloted, bean.approveDate);
}
```

Once this method goes out of scope, there is no longer a live reference to the object `bean` referred to and will be collected by the garbage collector at some point in the future.

That said, unless you're sure that instances of the `AddsBean` class are having a noticeable negative effect on the performance of your app, you should not worry about it. The performance of your application is probably affected far more by other operations. Returning a reference type (a type defined with `class` instead of `struct`) only passes a reference to the object, not the data of the object itself.

Comment: Technically, though, that's basically the same thing as using another class of fewer properties.

Comment: That's true, but C# doesn't have many other options for returning multiple values from methods.

Comment: @StephenJennings what you said is correct but i have one doubt might be i am wrong , as i know memory to properties allocated when you make object of class and out of all few properties is needed.

Comment: @HotCoolStud It's true that if you instantiate an object, the memory required to store the entire object is allocated. But, unless you have live references to hundreds of thousands of these objects simultaneously, the GC will clean up the memory once you're done with each instance. If you do have so many live references, then it's probably worth it to define a smaller class. If that's still not enough, then you have a specialized problem requiring knowledge of exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @HotCoolStud But before you put too much effort into optimizing the memory used by this specific object, you should be sure to instrument your application so you're sure this is really where you should be spending your time. The odds are good that you can get bigger performance wins by focusing your efforts elsewhere.

Comment: @StephenJennings thanks its just the point comes up ,so i just want to know story behind the secnes.